# Select if..can't find error

Tags: mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE payment 
    (`serial` int, `startdat` varchar(50),
   `enddat` varchar(50), `periode` varchar(50), `money` varchar(50))
;


INSERT INTO payment
    (`serial`, `startdat`, `enddat` , `periode` , `money` )
VALUES
    (1, '20180102','20200101','24','100'),
    (2, '20170102','20200101','36','100'),
    (3,'20180102','20190101','12','100');
SELECT
    (

        IF (
            PERIODE = 24,
            (
            IF (
                    (
                        '2018' BETWEEN (YEAR(STARTDAT))
                        AND (YEAR(ENDDATE))
                    ),
                    0,
                    (
                        ((money* 0.3) / 12) * (
                            IF (
                                (
                                    '2018' BETWEEN (YEAR(STARTDAT))
                                    AND (YEAR(ENDDATE))
                                ),
                                `12`,
                                (
                                IF (
                                        (`2018` = YEAR(STARTDAT)),
                                        (`12` - MONTH(STARTDAT) + 1),
                                        (
                                            IF (
                                                ('2018' = YEAR(ENDDATE)),
                                                (MONTH(ENDDATE) - 1),
                                                ''
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            (
                IF (
                    PERIODE = 36,
                    (
                    IF (
                            (
                                '2018' BETWEEN (YEAR(STARTDAT))
                                AND (YEAR(ENDDATE))
                            ),
                            0,
                            (
                                ((money* 0.2) / `12`) * (
                                    IF (
                                        (
                                            '2018' BETWEEN (YEAR(STARTDAT))
                                            AND (YEAR(ENDDATE))
                                        ),
                                        `12`,
                                        (
                                            IF (
                                                `2018` = YEAR (STARTDAT),
                                                (`12` - MONTH(STARTDAT) + 1),
                                                (
IF ((`2018` = YEAR (ENDDATE)),(MONTH(ENDDATE) - 1)),null)
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                (
                    IF (
                        (
                            '2018' BETWEEN (YEAR(STARTDAT))
                            AND (YEAR(ENDDATE))
                        ),
                        0,
                        ((money* 0.6) / `12`) * (
                            IF (
                                (
                                    '2018' BETWEEN (YEAR(STARTDAT))
                                    AND (YEAR(ENDDATE))
                                ),
                                `12`,
                                (
                                    IF (
                                        (`2018` = YEAR(STARTDAT)),
                                        (`12` - MONTH(STARTDAT) + 1),
                                        (
                                            IF (
                                                `2018` = YEAR (ENDDATE),
                                                (MONTH(ENDDATE) - 1),
                                                ''
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS '2018'
FROM
payment
```

Comment: What?? No explanation?! Can you add one pleeeeease :P I.e. Expected results, codes aim, problem you have, errors returned etc.

Comment: Hi sorry, first time user. I'm trying to calculated the amount that should be paid for 2018 demanding on the number of month, but it seems i can't get it right ( [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),null) ' at line 62 ) and I've tried every thing.